# How to check type being assigned to result of call operator?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make a simple matrix class

Relevant parts of "mymat.h"

```
#ifndef _MYMAT_H_GUARD_
#define _MYMAT_H_GUARD_

#include <iostream>

constexpr auto MYMAT_ERR_UNEXPECTED_TYPE = "Error, unexpected type!";
constexpr auto MYMAT_ERR_CODE_UNEXPECTED_TYPE = 0;
constexpr auto MYMAT_ERR_OUT_OF_BOUND = "Error, out of bound!";
constexpr auto MYMAT_ERR_CODE_OUT_OF_BOUND = 0;

template <typename T>
class MYMAT{
public:
    T* data;
    int x, y;
public:
    MYMAT(int x, int y);
    ~MYMAT();

    template <typename C>
    void set(int x, int y, C val);

    template<typename C>
    bool checkType(C val) const;
    
    void print_mat();

public:
    T& operator ()(int x, int y);

private:
    bool inRange(int x, int y);
};
#endif // !_MYMAT_H_GUARD_

template<typename T>
inline MYMAT<T>::MYMAT(int x, int y){
    this->data = new T[x * y]();
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

template<typename T>
inline MYMAT<T>::~MYMAT(){
    delete this->data;
}

template<typename T>
inline void MYMAT<T>::print_mat(){
    int x, y;
    for (y = 0; y < this->y; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < this->x; x++)
        {
            std::cout << this->data[y * this->x + x] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


template<typename T>
inline bool MYMAT<T>::inRange(int x, int y){
    return !((x < 1) && (x > this->x) && (y < 1) && (y > this->y));
}


template<typename T>
template<typename C>
inline void MYMAT<T>::set(int x, int y, C val){
    if (this->checkType(val)) {
        if (this->inRange(x, y)) {
            this->data[(y - 1) * this->x + (x - 1)] = val;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << MYMAT_ERR_OUT_OF_BOUND;
            exit(MYMAT_ERR_CODE_OUT_OF_BOUND);
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << MYMAT_ERR_UNEXPECTED_TYPE;
        exit(MYMAT_ERR_CODE_UNEXPECTED_TYPE);
    }
}


template<typename T>
inline T& MYMAT<T>::operator()(int x, int y)
{
    return this->data[this->x * (y - 1) + (x - 1)];
}

template<typename T>
template<typename C>
inline bool MYMAT<T>::checkType(C val) const
{
    return std::is_same_v<T, C>;
}
```

And below is how I call matrix and use `set` method

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mymat.h"

int main()
{

    MYMAT<int> m(3, 3);
    m.set(2, 2, 500);
    m.print_mat();
    m.set(2, 2, 500.0);
    m.print_mat();
}
```

It prints

```
0 0 0
0 500 0
0 0 0

Error, unexpected type!
```

But when call operator is used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mymat.h"

int main()
{

    MYMAT<int> m(3, 3);
    m(2, 2) = 500;
    m.print_mat();
    m(2, 2) = 500.0;
    m.print_mat();
}
```

It prints:

```
0 0 0
0 500 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 500 0
0 0 0
```

As you see, the value is casted from double to int.

How can I apply the condition in `set()` for call operator?

Comment: Unrelated: `_MYMAT_H_GUARD_` is an illegal identifier. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). It rarely bites, but when it does, it's a serious mind-<expletive deleted>.

Comment: Also unrelated: You may have left the special member functions out for brevity, but if not, give [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) a read.

Comment: Once you've returned the `T&`, there's not really a lot you can do to prevent calling code from messing around with it. If you want to force changes to values to go through the checks in `set`, you can change `operator()` to `const T& operator(int, int) const`, but that makes it read-only.

Comment: @NathanPierson has pretty much nailed it. `m(2, 2) = 500.0;` does no type checking and gleefully implicitly converts to the `double` to fit in an `int`. There's nothing I know of you can do to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want:

```
m(2, 2) = 500.0; // do custom checks for conversions from
                 // right hand side to left hand side
```

returning a `T&` from `operator()` is not going to work, because you have no control over implicit conversions to `T`. In this case, you can't prevent the conversion from `double` to `int`.

Instead, you can return a type from `operator()` that you write yourself, so you have all the control you need over implicit conversions. This type needs to hold onto the information on the left hand side, which is the `this` pointer of `m`, and the arguments to `operator()`. It only needs to support `operator=` to check for implicit conversions from the right hand side:

```
private:
struct Wrapper 
{
    MYMAT *t;  // holds onto the this pointer
    int x, y;
    
    template <typename C>
    void operator=(C val) 
    {
        t->set(x, y, val);  // uses MYMAT::set to do the conversion checking
    }
};
```

Now you can declare your `operator()` like this:

```
public:
    Wrapper operator ()(int x, int y);
```

and define it like this:

```
template<typename T>
inline auto MYMAT<T>::operator()(int x, int y) -> Wrapper
{
    return {this, x, y};
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K5W3rE).